# Angular animate make element slide up from bottom instead of slide down from top

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I recently tried Angular's animation on a slide in-out animation. I am having problem in getting my component to slide in from the bottom when `opening`. and then slide back down when `closing`.

I have an example of having the current sliding animation. Which slides down `from the top and back up`. How can I achieve to `slide up from button, and slide back down to the button` when closing?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/slide-in-out-qn

Answer (score 0):

Okay, That is happening because you are using `max-height`.

Change every `max-height` to `height` in your "animation.ts" and it will work